# echoing words in Python

Tags: python, string, echo

I need to write a function called `echo(word,x)` that takes as an argument a word and a value (called `x`) and returns the word repeated `x` times.

This is what I have but can't seem to figure out.

```
def echo("word",x):
   return "word" * x
```

Comment: don't use a string as a parameter, just use `def echo(word,x): return word * x`

Answer (score 2):

In the function definition, you must need to pass variables as function parameters.

```
def echo(stri,x):
   return stri * x

print(echo('foo', 5))
```